# Dockerfile needed when compose?

Tags: docker

I am trying to install [Jekyll](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/README.md) with Docker. I created my docker-compose file as explained in their readme. Now I wonder do I need to create additional a Dockerfile, or is the docker-compose sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker-compose uses a existing image that was already built so there is no need to use a dockerfile.

the dockerfile is used for creating new images or adding layers to an existing images.